# phpStorm autocompletion for composer files directive

Tags: php, composer-php, phpstorm

It seems that after upgrading to phpStorm8 the autocompletion for files that are required with the composer *files* directive is missing.
F.E:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "Stop": "src/"
    },
    "files": ["src/functions.php"]
}
```

This makes the composer autoloader require the files given in autoload_files.php file.

I used to get autocompletion for the functions in the required files, but not anymore.

Maybe its due to a change in the way composer loads the files or is it phpStorm?
How can i get the autocompletion working again?

Comment: Do a `composer dump-autoload` to make sure the autoloaders are up to date. Otherwise, this seems more like a support question for phpStorm.

Comment: PHPStorm doesn't really use Composer information to achieve autocompletion. If that fails, usually some (syntax) error in the file prevents PHPStorm from parsing and understanding the code.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in phpStorm 8.0.1 and will be fixed in 8.0.2.

It has nothing to do with composer but with a if block with function_exists around the function.

As i asked here:https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-25798
and it was fixed here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-23442